# SQL Help: A query that returns a row where a later row exists

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get a count of items in a particular component of a pipeline. Each time it moves within the pipeline, there is an entry created in this particular table.

It's stored something like this:

> ID:int-pk, ObjectId:varchar(25), EventType:int, Time:DateTime

For eg. I'm looking at time = 10:00

So if object 1 has event A at 9 AM and event 2 at 10 AM then I'd like to get the ObjectId (1).

### Characteristics

- The ObjectId is a unique id for the items going through the pipeline, so there will actually be very few of them (1 entry or each pipeline component, of which there are roughly 10)
- Expecting ~10K inserts/day
- Performance is a bit of a requirement (so EXISTS(...) might not be an option)
- Hardware is solid, it's a datacenter SQL machine, but it's shared with lots of other teams/processes.

Problems I've had/what I'm trying:

- It's a design right now, so I don't have actual data. I should have a proof of concept db up in a bit to test
- Here's a bit of what I've been thinking of trying:

---

```
select  objectid, time, eventtype
from        objects
where       -- can't use time < @t because I won't get the later events
group by    objectid
having      --
```

or

```
select        objectid as oid, time, eventtype
from          objects
where     eventtype = 1
and       time < @t
and       exists (select  objectid, eventtype, time
              where   objectid = oid -- not sure if this is legal
              and     eventtype = 2
              and     time > @t)
```

As you can probably tell, I don't write a whole lot of SQL so I've forgotten a bit.

### Example

```
ID  objectid    eventtype   time
1   12345   1   09:00 AM
2   12345   2   10:00 AM


eventtypeid     description 
1           "enter house"
2           "leave house"
3           "enter work"
```

So, the4 subject entered the house at 9am and left at 11am and I'm trying to see if they were in the house at 10am. 12345 is the subject's "name/number"

In this example, I'm trying to query to see if the subject was in the house at 10:00 AM. It's entirely possibly that the subject entered the house, but never left, and I don't want those for this query.

### Questions

- Am I on the right track?
- How could I estimate the expected performance of the second query (assuming it works)?
- Pointers? Suggestions? Examples?

Everything is appreciated.

Comment: You can use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to test your ideas, instead of procrastinating.

Comment: @muratgu: Fantastic, thank you. It's less about procrastinating, and more about too many meetings :(

Comment: @muratgu . . . Can you provide some sample data with the results that you want?  I still can't figure out why you want ObjectId(1) at 10:00 a.m. and not 2.  I can't figure out why your first line says "count" but all the examples are fetching lists.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I provided an example of what I'm looking for. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

For a given subject and a given time, you can do:

```
select top 1 o.*
from objects o
where eventtime < @t and
      objectid = @objectid
order by eventtime desc;
```

Extending this to multiple objects is easiest with windows functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid order by eventtime desc) as seqnum
      from objects o
      where eventtime < @t
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

These both give you information about the last event before (strictly before) a given time.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of confused by your SQL but it appears from what you state you want the most recent object in a given time frame potentially that already exists based on object reference.  I may be barking up the wrong tree as I am confused by the SQL but from what you ask for it apears you want an object that is grouped by having a common objectid that is not always unique and a type that is a generic type.

This may help you some it may not.  It basically will always account for dupes by their objectId counts but I was not sure if you limit scope by typ as well or not so I left it in case.  Then in the second iteration the dupes are partitioning by obj and then limiting scope by type as a variable potentially if you only care of one type.  You could do this in the first iteration as well.  If you encounter a null it assumes the type means 'everything'.  I have used similar methods like this in production environments so it should be solid as long as you have indexes in the proper places .  Namely indexes on Type and Datetime field.  Example is self extracting and will run as is in SQL Management Studio 2008 and higher with table variables that auto populate.

```
declare @Object Table ( objectId int , typ varchar(2), obj varchar(8), dt datetime);

insert into @Object values (1, 'A', 'Brett', getdate() - 0.8) ,(1,'A','Sean', getdate() - 0.4),(1,'A','Brett', getdate() - 0.08),(2,'A','Michael', getdate() - 0.04)
,(2,'B','Ray', getdate() - 0.008),(3, 'B', 'Erik', getdate() - 0.004),(3, 'C', 'Ray', getdate() - 0.0001);

-- objects as they are
Select *
from @Object
;

-- Find dupe objects by two distinctions
select 
    obj
,   count(objectId) over(partition by obj) as rowOccurencesByTyp
,   count(objectId) over(partition by typ, obj) as rowOccurencesByTypAndObj
from @Object
;


-- limit scope by type
declare 
-- CHANGE LINE AS NEEDED TO TEST HOW IT WORKS FOR 'A', 'B' OR NULL
    @Type varchar(2) = NULL  
-- Scope range of datetime too if you want
,   @dt datetime
;


-- Find dupes first
with dupes as 
    (
        select 
        obj
    ,   typ
    ,   dt
    ,   count(objectId) over(partition by obj) as rowOccurencesByTyp
    ,   count(objectId) over(partition by typ, obj) as rowOccurencesByTypAndObj
    -- I made the Ray occurence be in DIFFERENT Types so this would be an edge case you may not want
    from @Object
    -- WHERE CLAUSE WOULD BE HERE WITH DATE RANGE.  I was lazy in my example and made it small but you could 
    -- easily limit scope of dupes by a date range of 'dt between @Start and @End' or 'dt < @dt' or 'dt > @dt'
    )
-- if you merely want to get the most recent objects you can do a windowed function to get them quite easily
, a as 
    (
    select 
        *
    ,   row_number() over(partition by obj order by dt desc) as rwn
    -- I am find the ranking by shared objectid and then ordering by date descending(most current first). 
    -- You wish to also add the 'typ' before the objectID as I was not sure
    from dupes
    where typ = isnull(@Type, typ)  -- limit scope by type potentially
        and rowOccurencesByTyp > 1
    -- you may set up other rowOccurrences here if that suits you better.
    )
select *
from a
where rwn = 1  
-- recently inserted double is a dupe, determining scope of dupe is done by
-- the most recent 'rwn' finding a repeat insert of a row from part 1 
-- ordered by date descending and grouped by it's object
```

Comment: So, I wasn't very clear. I've provided an example to show more about what I'm asking for.

Comment: I am still not getting are you trying to capture a sequence of events or the first/last event in a sequence though?  The Row_Number() over() syntatic sugar is basically giving an integer to a sequence of events.  You can then iterate over that number to get either one or many values of an iteration of an event.  Like finding the first event, the last, the second to last, etc.  I think you would be best showing a simple table you have and what you want to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow what exactly you're after, but to return a row where a later row exists, simply, in SQL2012 can be done using the LEAD function:

```
DROP TABLE #test
CREATE TABLE #test (VALUE CHAR(25)) 
INSERT INTO #test VALUES('abcde'),('asaf'),('dogs'),(NULL),('')

SELECT Value, LEAD(Value,1,'Last Record') OVER (ORDER BY Value)
FROM #test

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Value, LEAD(Value,1,'Last Record') OVER (ORDER BY Value)'Last_Flag'
       FROM #test
      )sub
WHERE Last_Flag <> 'Last Record'
```

From the test table created above, the next query pulls a value from the next row (the 2nd parameter '1' defines the offset, how many rows forward you want to look) for each line, and 'Last Record' is seeded as the default value if there is no next row (NULL By default, which is fine unless your data has NULLS, I like to seed a value just in case).  Then the last one selects everything except for the one with no rows after.

You can add a PARTITION BY statement if you want to know for each objectID, IE:

```
LEAD(Value,1,'Last Record') OVER (PARTITION BY objectID ORDER BY Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've provided an example to show more about what I'm asking for. Does that clear it up?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added to your example to show a little more  sample data and most importantly the sample output you're looking for, so we can understand the logic needed.

Comment: Are you just trying to weed out crummy data?  Like, they leave the house 3 times in a row?  Luckily, any looking forward/back rows situation in SQL2012 is much more simple than previous versions.